# Interactive multi chart widget in jupyter notebook for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When using sparkmagic in Jupyter, it generates this interactive visualization of a dataframe. (full example at from https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/examples/Pyspark%20Kernel.ipynb). How to achieve the same visualization controls for a normal python notebook having pandas dataframe objects?

No matter what I install the dataframe when viewed in a cell, shows up only as a table.

[image: plotly jupyter widget]

Answer (score 0):

Posted the same question on their github page - https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/issues/478

@apetresc helped me with this link - https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/autovizwidget/examples/autoviz.ipynb

Idea is to use `autovizwidget` library like this,

```
from autovizwidget.widget.utils import display_dataframe
display_dataframe(df)
```